# undefine method following Railscasts 154

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I am quite the newbie here.

I have been following Railscasts 154 but when I try submitting a comment, I get this error:

```
undefined method `classify' for nil:NilClass
```

I little debugging has pointed me to this:

```
(rdb:5) name =~ /(.+)_id$/
0
```

debugging `name` comes up with `micropost_id` but $i is somehow returning `nil`.

```
  private
  def find_commentable
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
        debugger
        return $i.classify.constantize.find(value)
      end
    end
    nil
  end
```

How do I get past this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
return $i.classify.constantize.find(value)
```

should be:

```
return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
```

`$1` is a global variable storing the first matched group from the regular expression match result.

Comment: OMG. typo! how could I miss that. Yeah, I know it's regular expression :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `$i.classify` should've been `$1.classify`. In ruby `$1, $2, ...` are global variables which hold the value of the last regexp-matched group. In this case $1 will contain whatever is in parenthesis in your regexp: `/(.+)_id$/`.

In your case `$i` is `nil`, therefore you get error trying to call `classify` on `nil`.

Comment: sorry guys about this. It was a typo on my end. I should wear glasses.